# Python PyQt5 Create Layout

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a layout with pyqt5, but i cannot do it. There are so many error. Why i am getting so many errors.

[image: Codes and errors]

Comment: try to upload code rather than a screenshot : )

Answer (score 2):

`autoFillBackground()` takes no arguments, and `MainWindow` will not assume the palette of it's central widget unless you explicitly set it. Also, this has nothing to do with a layout.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Color(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.autoFillBackground()
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(palette)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget = Color('Blue')
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.setPalette(widget.palette())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @alec QColor *does* accept "Blue", as all [SVG color keyword names](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords): [color = `QColor("name")`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#QColor-5) is equivalent to [`color = QColor(); color.setNamedColor("name")`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#setNamedColor)